# Invalid column name 'e01' in SQL query

Tags: c#, sql-server

i have database contain column name `Code` data type `nvarchar(50)` i connected to my database by c# and created a SQL command  as

```
string code = "e01";
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("select * from inv where code = " + code + ";", conn);
SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
```

i found an error says

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information: Invalid column name 'e01'.
```

and if i but number instead of `e01` it work fine ..

Comment: After reading the answers, also read about sql injection and prepared queries.

Comment: Fix your statement to use parameters and you won't need to worry about how to wrap fields. The parameter will handle it for you. Plus your current code is not secure and can allow someone to completely corrupt your database.

Comment: Going off what @SimpleVar suggests, read about [little Bobby Tables.](https://xkcd.com/327/)

Comment: Voting to close. Typo.

Answer (score 6):

your are missing quotes. Try this:

```
string code = "e01"
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("select * from inv where code = '" + code + "';", conn);
SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
```

Also, it's recomended use parameters instead concatenating values. This avoid sql injection attacks or sql errors if your code contains special characters, like quotes:

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("select * from inv where code = @pCode", conn);
command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@pCode", code));
SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
```

Comment: You should also mention the SQL injection vulnerability in this...

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to put quotes around your column value, because `e01` is a value and not a column it needs to be surrounded by single quotes.

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("select * from inv where code = '" + code + "';", conn);
```